# How to send the saved auth-token in another request?

Tags: karate

```
Scenario: Verify that Authentication is done or not
Given url '***********'
Given path 'authenticate'
And form field username = 'admin_cs'
And form field password = '********'
When method post
Then status 200
And header tokenn = response.token

* def accessToken = response.token

* print accessToken


Scenario: Verify Get all Clients

Given url '************'
Given path 'users/usersAssignable'
* header x-auth-token = accessToken
When method get
Then status 200
* def response = response
* print response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please combine the two `Scenario`-s into one. Or move the first one here into the `Background`. Please read this very carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure

Comment: Thanks Peter it helped me to resolve the issue and a small suggestion can you please elaborate the document a bit so that any one can understand the things easily.

Comment: @srinuratnala - wow, are you serious !? instead why don't you suggest where exactly the documentation needs to be fixed ?

Comment: yeah i can tell you, lets say someone is hitting one post api and the response they need to get it in a seperate file and another case where they can get all the saved variables into a single file like environment variables. I hope this would be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: @srinuratnala pretty clear you haven't bothered to read the existing documentation. thanks anyway.